# How to encrypt access tokens in react native using react-native-keychain?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, security, encryption

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#managing-security-tokens

So I have tried implementing the encryption for the auth tokens in the react native code that are fetched from the auth package of react-native. And I have written the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

const MYSTORAGE_KEY_PREFIX = '@ACCESSTOKEN:';
let dataMemory = {};

export default class MyStorage {
  static syncPromise = null;

  static setItem(key, value) {

    Keychain.setGenericPassword(MYSTORAGE_KEY_PREFIX + key, value);
    dataMemory[key] = value

    return dataMemory[key]
  }

  static getItem(key) {

    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataMemory, key) ? dataMemory[key] : undefined
  }

  static removeItem(key) {
    Keychain.resetGenericPassword()
    return delete dataMemory[key]
  }

  static clear() {
    dataMemory = {}
    return dataMemory
  }
  static sync(){
    if (!MyStorage.syncPromise) {
        MyStorage.syncPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
          Auth.currentSession().then(data => {MyStorage.setItem(data.idToken.jwtToken)})
        });
    }
    return MyStorage.syncPromise;
}

}

Auth.configure({
  storage: MyStorage
});
```

Now, Is it the right way to do this? How do I verify if the tokens are encrypted? I'm completely new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I have with react-native-encrypted-storage

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage';

const AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX = '@AuthorizationStorage:';

let dataMemory: Record<string, string> = {};

/**
 * A class representing the storage for authentication-related data.
 * Used by Amplify for secure storage of user data.
 * @see https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/react-native/#managing-security-tokens
 */
export class AuthorizationStorage {
  /**
   * A promise used for synchronization.
   */
  static syncPromise: Promise<void> | null = null;

  /**
   * Sets an item in the storage.
   * @param key - The key of the item to set.
   * @param value - The value of the item to set.
   * @returns The stored value or null if the value is not provided.
   */
  static setItem(key: string, value?: unknown): string | null {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX + key, 'null');
      EncryptedStorage.setItem(AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX + key, value);
      dataMemory[key] = value;
      return dataMemory[key]!;
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Gets an item from the storage.
   * @param key - The key of the item to get.
   * @returns The stored value or null if the item does not exist.
   */
  static getItem(key: string): string | null {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataMemory, key)
      ? dataMemory[key]!
      : null;
  }

  /**
   * Removes an item from the storage.
   * @param key - The key of the item to remove.
   * @returns True if the item was removed, false otherwise.
   */
  static removeItem(key: string): boolean {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem(AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX + key);
    EncryptedStorage.getItem(AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX + key).then((value) => {
      if (value) {
        EncryptedStorage.removeItem(AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX + key);
      }
    });
    return delete dataMemory[key];
  }

  /**
   * Clears the storage.
   * @returns An empty record representing the cleared data.
   */
  static clear(): Record<string, string> {
    dataMemory = {};
    return dataMemory;
  }

  /**
   * Synchronizes data from storage.
   * @returns A promise that resolves when synchronization is complete or rejects with an error.
   */
  static async sync(): Promise<void> {
    if (AuthorizationStorage.syncPromise === null) {
      AuthorizationStorage.syncPromise = (async () => {
        try {
          const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
          const memoryKeys = (keys || []).filter((key: string) =>
            key.startsWith(AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX)
          );

          const promises: Promise<void>[] = [];
          for (const key of memoryKeys) {
            const value = await EncryptedStorage.getItem(key);
            if (value) {
              dataMemory[key.replace(AUTH_STORAGE_KEY_PREFIX, '')] = value;
            }
          }

          await Promise.all(promises);
        } catch (error: unknown) {
          throw error;
        }
      })();
    }
    return AuthorizationStorage.syncPromise;
  }
}
```

And then in my config

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    ..., // (user-pool-id, region etc.)
    storage: AuthorizationStorage
  }
})
```